# Swap digits in a string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to obtain the serial number of a hdd and the result is for example `"1234567890"`, even though the real serial number is `"2143658709"`, so I need a script to swap the numbers.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
$pass = ""
$t = (Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmedia).serialnumber
$t -split '(.{2})' |%{
  if ($_ -ne "") {
    $pass += [CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16))
  }
}
write host $pass
```

I want to swap the adjecent digits, like this:

```
$output = Swap-Digits '1234567890'
$output -eq '2143658709'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your question is a little unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what code did you tried and whats not working in it?

Comment: i used $pass=""
$t=(Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmedia).serialnumber
$t -split '(.{2})' |%{ if ($_ -ne "") { $pass+=[CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16))  }}
write host $pass to get the serial number of the hdd and the result is example "1234567890" , the real serial number is "2143658709" so i need a script to swap the numbers

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Would you mind editing the question to include this information?

Comment: `WMIC DISKDRIVE GET SERIALNUMBER` ?

Comment: You asked the question twice?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934557/powershell-get-wmiobject-win32-physicalmedia-serialnumber-output-hex/59939465#59939465  I think this string is in format "middle endian", like I said in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myVar = "1234567890"


for ($i=0; $i -lt $myvar.length; $i+=2){
    $revChars += $myvar[$i+1]
    $revChars += $myvar[$i]
    }

$revChars
```