# powershell (Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmedia).serialnumber output hex

Tags: powershell

When I used `(Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmedia).serialnumber` the output was in hex. Example: `31323334353637383930`.  Then then I used the code below

```
$pass=""
$t=(Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmedia).serialnumber
$t -split '(.{2})' |%{ if ($_ -ne "") { $pass+=[CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16))  }}
write host $pass
```

The output was: `1234567890`.  The problem is that `1234567890` is not the serial number -- the real serial number is `2143658709`.  I need a script to swap the number `$input "1234567890"` to `$output "214365768709"`.

Comment: when i use your GWMI code, i get valid serial numbers for all my HDD & SSD items. they match what i get calling the `CIM_DiskDrive` class, also. ///// your "output in hex" comment makes no sense - the numeric string you show is all standard digits. **_why do you think it is a hexadecimal number?_**

Comment: You can see hair:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8545f076-2a0c-4d5a-b93d-7dbc70c3ceec/how-do-i-use-wmi-to-get-the-correct-serial-number-for-hdds?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: i just need to swap the numbers like in the example  $input "1234567890" to $output "214365768709".

Comment: thank you for the clarification. since it isn't HEX, just reversing the pairs of digits, i used that as the idea in the Answer i posted. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this presumes your SN string is an even number of characters, and that the real number simply reverses the character pairs.

```
$InString = '1234567890'

$OutString = ''
foreach ($Index in 0..($InString.Length / 2))
    {
    $CurPos = $Index * 2
    $OutString += $InString[$CurPos + 1] + $InString[$CurPos]
    }

$OutString
```

output = `2143658709`

Comment: @Xwlu - you are most welcome! [*grin*] if this works as you need it to work, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called "middle endian" format, where every two bytes are reversed:  [middle-endian](https://catb.org/jargon/html/M/middle-endian.html)

Coming from a post here:  [WMI Win32_PhysicalMedia SMART ID in Vista and 7 Permissions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8523d7b9-0dc8-4d87-be69-a482aec9ee5e/wmi-win32physicalmedia-smart-id-in-vista-and-7-permissions?forum=netfxbcl)